# Is it possible to change the yaml base file location for Open API specification?

Tags: spring, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

Is there any configuration that must be done in order to change the location of the yaml file in which the specification is described?

[Open API url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7czEO.png)

In the attached picture I would like to set /swagger-ui/open-api.yaml instead of /open-api.

I tried to change the file path by setting the following property:

springdoc:
swagger-ui:
url: /swagger-ui/open-api.yaml

But I receive 404 not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`springdoc: swagger-ui: url: /swagger-ui/open-api.yaml` is not a proper configuration.

Change this to `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/swagger-ui/open-api.yaml` and place it in your `application.properties`.

If you are using a `application.yml`, then make sure the property is also properly set in its associated configuration class as well.  Also, sometimes yaml files have trouble parsing urls as a string, so try wrapping it in quotes.

Comment: We are using application.yml.
It worked by putting the path in quotes. Thank you!